# How to go through a range and fill another worksheet's cells with the values?

Tags: vba, excel

In my Excel worksheet I have something like this:

```
          1      2      3
         John   Paul   Mike     
1  John   0      1      1
2  Paul   1      0
3  Mike   1             0
```

Which is similar to a symmetric matrix. Note that:

- Each person has an ID;
- For simplification, I set the values to 1's, but they can go from 1
  to 20. 0's will always be 0's. There are also some blank spaces.

What I need is a macro that goes through the *"matrix"* and outputs the values into another worksheet in the following format:

```
From     To     Strenght
  1      2        1
  1      3        1
  2      1        1
  3      1        1
```

This is what I have so far, but isn't working because it return the error "The object is required", pointing to `strenghts`.

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, strenghts As Integer

    Set currentCell = Worksheets("Raw_Relationships").Cells(3, 3)

         For i = 1 To 145
         For j = 1 To 145

           If currentCell <> "" Then

             Set currentCell = Worksheets("Raw_Relationships").Cells(i, j).Offset(2, 3)
             Set strenghts = Worksheets("Raw_Relationships").Cells(i, j).Offset(2, 2).Value

             Set Worksheets("Gephi_Data").Cells(i, 1).Offset(150, 0).Value = i
             Set Worksheets("Gephi_Data").Cells(i, 2).Offset(150, 0).Value = j
             Set Worksheets("Gephi_Data").Cells(i, 3).Offset(150, 0).Value = strenghts

           End If

         Next j
         Next i
```

Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve what you want. Here is a very basic example of what you want.

Let's say your sheet looks like this

[image]

Use this code. I have commented the code so that you shouldn't have a problem understanding it. If you do then simply ask :)

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim rw As Long, col As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> This is where the output will be generated
    rw = 2: col = 8

    With ws
        '~~> Create Headers of Output
        .Cells(1, col).Value = "From"
        .Cells(1, col + 1).Value = "To"
        .Cells(1, col + 2).Value = "Strength"

        '~~> Looping through rows
        For i = 3 To 5
            '~~> Looping through columns
            For j = 3 To 5
                '~~> Check if the cell is > 0
                If .Cells(i, j).Value > 0 Then
                    '~~> Write the `From` column
                    .Cells(rw, col).Value = .Cells(i, 1).Value
                    '~~> Write the `To` Column
                    .Cells(rw, col + 1).Value = .Cells(1, j).Value
                    '~~> Write the `Strength` Column
                    .Cells(rw, col + 2).Value = .Cells(i, j).Value
                    rw = rw + 1
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**Output**

I am generating the output in Col `H` onwards. Change as applicable.

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you! I guess I was over-complicating it.

Some quick questions:
- Is 'With ws' used to set the Worksheet I define earlier as the active one?
- Do you always have to use the period (.) before Cells?

Thank you very much once again, this definitely gave me a boost in understanding VBA and wanting to learn more!

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `Set` in `Set strenghts = ...`. Just write `strenghts = ...`. `Set` is only used to set references to objects. `strenghts` isn't an object, it's a numeric value.

Also, I'm not sure if the typo in `strenghts` is intentional, but it's usually spelled "streng**th**s".